# How do I parse an expression '^#[0-9A-F]{2}\$[0-9A-F]{4}/$' effectively in perl

Tags: c, perl, parsing, scanf

I have to parse data strings returned by GIA10N module. The response string consists of 9 bytes ASCII codes with the pattern

```regex
    ^#[0-9A-F]{2}\$[0-9A-F]{4}/$
```

.

Description:

```
      DIGITS  123456789
        CODE  #FF$DDDD/
           #  -- Response token
          FF  -- Function code 00-FF
           $  -- delimiter
        DDDD  -- Data value 0000-FFFF
           /  -- Terminal symbol
```

Example:

```
     #0A$F831  -- means value -1999 from function 0A
```

Usually the sscanf function will do the job in C to decode this string.

```c
    #include <stdio.h>
    
    int parseData(char *data, int prn) {
        char ff[3]  = "\0";

        unsigned int udddd  = 0;
        int sdddd  = 0;
    
        if (sscanf(data,"#%2s$%X/",ff,&udddd) !=2) {
            printf("ERROR parsing %s\n", data);
            return 0;
        }

        sdddd =  (int) udddd;
        if (sdddd & 0x8000)
                sdddd -= 0x10000;
        if (prn)
            printf("CODE:%s PARSED: %s %d\n", data, ff, sdddd);
        return 1;
    }
    
    int main(int argc, char **argv)
    {
        parseData("#0A$F831/", 1);
        return 0;
    }
```

With a runtime:

```bash
    $ gcc test-scan.c -o test-scan
    $ time ./test-sprintf
    CODE: #0A$F831/ PARSED:  -1999

    real    0m0.003s
    user    0m0.000s
    sys     0m0.000s
```

In perl the function sscanf in conjuction with the format %X is not avialable. I have to tailor and split the message and do the hex/ 16 bit conversion magic which is much slower.

```perl
    #!/usr/bin/env perl
    use warnings;
    use strict;
    
    sub parseData($$) {
        my ($msg, $print) = @_;
        my ($ff,$dddd) = split /\$/, substr($msg, 1, length($msg)-2);
        $dddd = hex($dddd);
        $dddd -= 0x10000 if $dddd & 0x8000;
        printf "CODE: %s PARSED: %s %d\n", $msg, $ff, $dddd
            if $print;
    }
    
    parseData('#0A$F831/', 1);
```

Check the perl runtime:

```bash
    $ time ./test-scan.pl
    CODE: #0A$F831/ PARSED: 0A -1999

    real    0m0.012s
    user    0m0.008s
    sys     0m0.000s
```

I there an other way to speed this up without using another language?

**Addendum**

According to the answers and concepts of [ike](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63769998/3338646) and [polar bear](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63770664/3338646) and my approach:

```perl
    #!/usr/bin/env perl
    use warnings;
    use strict;
    use Benchmark qw( cmpthese );
    
    my %tests = (
       ike  => q{
          my ($ff, $dddd) = $msg =~ m{^#([0-9A-F]{2})\$([0-9A-F]{4})/\z}
             or die("Error parsing \"$msg\"\n");
    
          $dddd = hex($dddd);
       },
       huck  => q{
          (my ($ff,$dddd) = split(/\$/, substr($msg, 1, length($msg)-2))) == 2
             or die("Error parsing \"$msg\"\n");
          $dddd = hex($dddd);
       },
       pbear => q{
           my($ff,$dddd) = unpack('xA2xA4',$msg);
           $dddd = hex($dddd);
       },
    );
    
    $_ = "use strict; use warnings; our \$msg; for (1..1000) { $_ }"
       for values %tests;
    
    local our $msg = '#0A$F831/';
    cmpthese(-3, \%tests);
```

I got this benchmark results:

```bash
    /usr/bin/perl -w "bench-cvx-data.pl"
            Rate   ike  huck pbear
    ike   1070/s    --  -33%  -41%
    huck  1596/s   49%    --  -12%
    pbear 1816/s   70%   14%    --
```

Comment: Using `my ($ff, $dddd) = unpack 'xA2xA4x', $msg;` is a few percent faster than your `substr` based one on my system, fwiw.

Comment: Also note your C version has undefined behavior - in `sscanf()`, you're passing a pointer to a `short` to a format that expects a pointer to an `unsigned int`. If your compiler isn't warning you about this, turn up the warning options (`-Wall -Wextra` is a good start for gcc and clang).

Comment: @Shawn Thanks for the advise, so it seems the implemetation has an error. I found that C code snippet in the implementation in exact that way.  I've corrected the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```regex
^#[0-9A-F]{2}\$[0-9A-F]{4}/$
```

matches 9 or 10 characters. I think you meant

```regex
^#[0-9A-F]{2}\$[0-9A-F]{4}/\z
```

---

Your code simplifies to the following:

```perl
my ($ff, $dddd) = $msg =~ m{^#([0-9A-F]{2})\$([0-9A-F]{4})/\z}
   or die("Error parsing \"$msg\"\n");

$dddd = hex($dddd);
```

That said, this is *slower* than your version. It's far more readable, though.

The following is equally readable as mine, equally fast as yours, but non-validating:

```perl
my ($ff, $dddd) = unpack('x a2 x a4', $msg);
$dddd = hex($dddd);
```

---

That said, 12 ms is what it takes to simply load `perl` for me (although only 5 ms on a different machine).

```
$ time perl -e1

real    0m0.012s
user    0m0.016s
sys     0m0.000s
```

Are trying to optimize something that takes less than 1 ms?

So I wrote a benchmark. For me,

- Your version took 1/1232000 s = 0.81 μs
- My version took 1/636000 s = 1.3 μs

Benchmark:

```perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use Benchmark qw( cmpthese );

my %tests = (
   ike  => q{
      my ($ff, $dddd) = $msg =~ m{^#([0-9A-F]{2})\$([0-9A-F]{4})/\z}
         or die("Error parsing \"$msg\"\n");

      $dddd = hex($dddd);
   },
   huck  => q{
      ( my ($ff,$dddd) = split /\$/, substr($msg, 1, length($msg)-2) ) == 2
         or die("Error parsing \"$msg\"\n");

      $dddd = hex($dddd);
   },
);

$_ = "use strict; use warnings; our \$msg; for (1..1000) { $_ }"
   for values %tests;

local our $msg = '#0A$F831/';
cmpthese(-3, \%tests);
```

Representative output:

```
       Rate  ike huck
ike   752/s   -- -39%
huck 1232/s  64%   --
```

Comment: Thanks that works fine and is elegant with the same runtime, but how do I compensate the sscanf  %X problem.

Comment: To what problem are you referring?

Comment: Thanks the time calculation experiment you wrote is very inspiring. I have to deal with two problems. 1 for an migration of a sensor field (running several RS485 busses). I WANT to use the perl enviroment because of the VALIDATION feature and the easy to write net communication features. The old implementation was written in on an industry PC (2000er running XP/ cygwin). 2. I want to migrate that tech/logic to a smaller embedded linux device with a slower clock rate and was not shure if I can leave the C programming terrain.

Answer (score 1):

In OP's code `sscanf` assumes that input data have constant width of fields.

For such structured input data, function `unpack` is a good alternative

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $in = '#0A$F831/';

my($hex_func,$hex_val) = unpack('xA2xA4',$in);
my $value = hex $hex_val;

$value = (($value^0xFFFF)+1)*-1 if $value & 0x8000;

say "
    Function: $hex_func
    Value:    $value
";
```

Output

```
    Function: 0A
    Value:    -1999
```

[perlpacktut](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlpacktut.html#Packing-Text)